# How to do Bootstrap navigation dropdown?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap css with my Html.
Here's my code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Burger's</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fries</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Milkshakes</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

It does not create a dropdown link.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have added 3 files

1. jquery library file before bootstrap.js
2. bootstrap.js
   and

   3. bootstrap.css in your head tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">    
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Burger's</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fries</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Milkshakes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Try this. In any case for reference: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what else you have coded as you haven't shared your *demo* file.

In case, you haven't referred to the Bootstrap's site which illustrates how to add a button dropdown, please refer it this website - [**Bootstrap Button Dropdown**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns).